# Match an IP in a Multi-Line string in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm trying to match the subnet portion of an IP address that is a multi-line string.

Here is the code:

> a_sdp = "v=0
>   o=- 20064 20065 IN IP4 172.26.201.100
>   s=SDP data
>   c=IN IP4 172.26.201.100
>   t=0 0
>   m=audio 12662 RTP/AVP 0 101
>   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>   a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
>   a=fmtp:101 0-15
>   a=ptime:20  ";
>
> rgex = "c=IN%sIP4%s(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)%.";
>
> a_subnet = string.match(a_sdp,rgex,1);

I'm trying to match `c=IN IP4 172.26.201`and store capture `172.26.201` in group 1.

I've tried all sorts of things but I can't even seem to match even one value much less the portion of the ip address. I always get `a_subnet = null`.

Comment: Try `%s+` instead of `%s`

Comment: A `match` with multiple captures will return multiple results.  You need to catch them all with something like: `table.concact({string.match(a_sdp,rgex,1)},'.')`

Comment: Multi-line strings in Lua are enclosed in [[ ... ]] with any matching number of = in between the square brackets

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler pattern:

```
a_sdp = [[v=0
o=- 20064 20065 IN IP4 172.26.201.100
s=SDP data
c=IN IP4 172.26.201.100
t=0 0
m=audio 12662 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=ptime:20
]]

print(a_sdp:match("c=IN%s+IP4%s*(.-)\n"))
```